# Magento and outputting of User Agent in Transactional Emails

Tags: magento

I am looking to output the "user agent" information of the client who placed an order through our Magento driven shopping cart.

I've figured out that **{{var order.getRemoteIp()}}** outputs the IP address of the client.
I need a way to output the user-agent of the client, as well.

Is it even possible?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for 1.5 (as you didn't specify a version), I would say it's not possible as they have no provision for storing that info on the order or quote. You could write and extension to help you with that, but as it stands it seems to be in the 'not possible' category.